# Expand $-(x-2y)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having a hard time solving this. this is a part of a bigger "count sequence" and I need to expand:

$$-(x-2y)^2$$

Bigger "part":

$$(x+2y)^2-(x-2y)^2-4x(2y-1)$$

Doesn't matter how much I twist it, I end up with:

$$x^2-4xy+4y$$

When apparently, this is correct:

$$ x^2+4xy-4y^2$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AlexR Sorry, I will improve:)

Comment: Note that $(x+2y)^2-(x-2y)^2$ is just a special product called "difference of squares". What is $(x+2y)+(x-2y)$? What is $(x+2y)-(x-2y)$

Answer (score 2):

we have $-(x-2y)^2=-(x^2-4xy+4y^2)=-x^2-4y^2+4xy$

Comment: isn't your answer and Rainier van Es the same?